# Combine array of string and number as object array conditionally

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, lodash

I have two array, one is type of String and second one is number. How can I combine these conditionally as key value objects.

**For example:**

```
var fruits = [
  "Apple",
  "Banana" ,
  "Apricot",
  "Bilberry"
]

var count = [3,5,0,2]
```

I want to combine `fruits` and `count` array as key value object and **which count is not** **`0`**

**Expected:**

```
var merge = [{"Apple":3},{"Banana" :5},{"Bilberry":2}]
```

**What i have tried is:**

```
var merge = _.zipObject(["Apple","Banana" ,"Apricot","Bilberry"], [3,5,0,2])
```

and result is:

```
{"Apple":3,"Banana":5 ,"Apricot":0,"Bilberry":2}
```

Comment: why not loop thorugh and do it yourself. i don't think there is any readymade function for this

Comment: @Abhishek, yes can do by loop, but its to fatigue :)

Comment: library will do same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this vanilla js solution as well using `filter`, `Object.values` and `map`

```
var output = count.map((s, i) => ({
  [fruits[i]]: s
})).filter(s => Object.values(s)[0]);
```

**Demo**

```js
var fruits = [
  "Apple",
  "Banana",
  "Apricot",
  "Bilberry"
];

var count = [3, 5, 0, 2];

var output = count.map((s, i) => ({
  [fruits[i]]: s
})).filter(s => Object.values(s)[0]);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: You might want to first `map` and only *then* `filter`, since the counts are now shifting one index away from the fruits.

Comment: @user3297291 You are right about it, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create the object with `_.zipObject()`, and then use [`_.pickBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#pickBy) to filter keys with 0 values.

**Note:** `_.pickBy()` accepts a callback. The default is identity, which will filter all falsy values (false, 0, null, undefined, etc...). If you want to filter just zeroes, supply another callback, for example `(v) => v !== 0`.

```js
var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Apricot", "Bilberry"];
var count = [3,5,0,2];

var result = _.pickBy(_.zipObject(fruits, count));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With vanilla JS, you can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Apricot", "Bilberry"];
var count = [3,5,0,2];

var result = fruits.reduce(function(r, f, i) {
  if(count[i]) r[f] = count[i];
  
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to create a new array of objects & `filter` to remove the undefined

The source of `undefined` is teh callback function is not returning any value when the count is 0

```js
var fruits = [
  "Apple",
  "Banana",
  "Apricot",
  "Bilberry"
]

var count = [3, 5, 0, 2]
var newArr = count.map(function(item, index) {
  if (item !== 0) {
    return {
      [fruits[index]]: item
    }
  }
}).filter(function(item) {
  return item !== undefined;

})

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The two utility functions I think you're looking for are:

- `zip`, to go from `[ a, b ] + [ 1, 2 ] -> [ [ a, 1 ], [ b, 2 ] ]`
- `fromPair` to go from `[ a, 1 ] -> { a: 1 }`

Splitting the transformation in these two steps allows you to filter your list of key-value-pairs, which ensures you don't loose track of the link by index:

```
const valueFilter = ([k, v]) => v !== 0;
```

Possible implementations for those functions are:

```
const zip = (xs, ...others) =>
  xs.map(
    (x, i) => [x].concat(others.map(ys => ys[i]))
  );

const fromPair = ([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v });
```

With those utilities, you can do:

```js
// Utils
const zip = (xs, ...others) =>
  xs.map(
    (x, i) => [x].concat(others.map(ys => ys[i]))
  );
  
const fromPair = ([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v });

// Data
const fruits = [ "Apple", "Banana", "Apricot", "Bilberry" ];
const counts = [3,5,0,2];

// App
const valueNotZero = ([k, v]) => v !== 0;

console.log(
  zip(fruits, counts)
    .filter(valueNotZero)
    .map(fromPair)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

With simple `forEach`

```js
var fruits = [
  "Apple",
  "Banana",
  "Apricot",
  "Bilberry"
]

var count = [3, 5, 0, 2];
var merge = [];

fruits.forEach((val, i) => {
  if (count[i]) { merge.push({ [val]: count[i] }) };
});

console.log(merge);
```